# Already deleted relationships in Neo4j Database

Tags: neo4j, cypher

We got a problem with the neo4j database. I was running this query, after a minute the docker container stopped and the database needed a to be restarted manually.

```
start r=relationship(*) 
match (s)-[r]->(e)
with s,e,type(r) as typ, tail(collect(r)) as coll 
WHERE coll <> []
RETURN COUNT(coll)
```

The only thing that we see in the logging is a lot of deleted relationships. There is no delete query running. It there something wrong with the db/ can it be fixed? The error message is:

```
Unable to delete relationship[5146889] since it is already deleted.
```

Version is 3.1.1

Neo is running on docker (swarm). But only a cluster of 1.

Comment: I can't think of any way this would result in any kind of deletion. Can you provide your neo4j version, and if this is a part of a cluster? You may want to examine your transaction logs of this time to see what may have happened. Your other logs may also hold clues.

Comment: Thx for the reaction. Added some info. What other logs should i examen beside the transaction logs?

Comment: I now got the data of the database, and i see that the transaction logs are 22 gig of a total of 24 gig db. Can this be a part of the problem?

Comment: Probably not part of the problem, unless you're at the limit of your total disk space. You may want to limit your tx logs in your neo4j.conf file (especially if you're using community edition, tx logs won't be as important). See [this configuration property](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/configuration-settings/#config_dbms.tx_log.rotation.retention_policy).

Comment: I is limited to 7days, we will change it to 3. The backup is done daily. We are using the enterprise edition on a startup licence.